# CodeIgniter failed when the url does not end with the suffix .html

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in CodeIgniter. I setup CI in my localhost Eg. localhost/MyProjects/CodeIgniter/welcome/index

The url_config in my config.php is this:

```
$config['url_suffix'] = ".html";
```

When i access the URL eg.

```
http://localhost/MyProjects/CodeIgniter/welcome/index
```

or

```
http://localhost/MyProjects/CodeIgniter/welcome/index.html
```

the page is loaded.

My question is, how to set CodeIgniter failed when the url does not end with the suffix .html?
So, when i type like this

```
http://localhost/MyProjects/CodeIgniter/welcome/index
```

the request will fail or redirect to forbidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this to redirect it :

```
$this->load->helper('url'); 
if (preg_match("/.html/i", current_url())) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    // redirect(base_url());
    show_404(); //if you want to show page not found
}
```

place inside your `function index()` in `welcome.php` controller.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your solution, but i give some modification to your solution like this

```
if (preg_match("/.html/i", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    // redirect(base_url());
    show_404(); //if you want to show page not found
}
```

because if I use the `current_url()` function, then CodeIgniter always provide `.html` extension that has been set in the `$config['url_suffix']='.html';`
so I use the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` because it provides what is actually there in the address bar.

Thanks for your advice, my problem was solved. If you are from Indonesia, makasih gan